# Run function after .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having the following html code:

```
<div>
   <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

When the div with id="a" is clicked, I want to replace this div with the following div:

```
<div id="b"></div>
```

I managed to create the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucant5uy/
In this fiddle, you can see that the first function (#a is clicked) runs perfect, but the second function (#b is clicked) doesn't run, because the div #b doesn't exist when the page is loaded.

Then I decided to put the second function inside the first function: http://jsfiddle.net/ucant5uy/2/. As you can see, you can click #a once, and #b once, and then the code stops working. I want to be able to click #a and #b as many times as I would like to. I know you can achieve this with some simple CSS tricks (adding both divs to the HTML and using display:none;), but I'm wondering wether it's possible to achieve the same thing using .append().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sort of question has been asked a thousand times. You can easily find an answer here on stackoverflow. That method is commonly called *"Event delegation"*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: How is a question like this which has so many other predecessors , getting this many upvotes?!!! Just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the function to the parent div (and it is as `main`), which exist in the DOM and will exist, otherwise you can assign the function only to the elements, which already exist in DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main').on("click","#a",function() {
            $(this).parent().append('<div id="b"></div>');
            $(this).remove();
        })
        
        $('#main').on("click","#b",function() {
            $(this).parent().append('<div id="a"></div>');
            $(this).remove();
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works smoothly. I'll 'check' your answer in 11 minutes (because stackoverflow won't let me 'ckeck' it right now)

Answer (score 2):

use .on() for future elements event handler

```
$("div").on('click','div#b',function() {

        $(this).parent().append('<div id="a"></div>');
        $(this).remove();
    })
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("div").on('click','div#a',function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="b"></div>');
        $(this).remove();
    })
    
    $("div").on('click','div#b',function() {
       
        $(this).parent().append('<div id="a"></div>');
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

```css
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}

#a, #b {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#a {
    background-color:green;
}

#b {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```